# regexp - search for backslash if it's not used to escape another character

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a large amount of javascript and php files and I must check in each of these files if I used a single `\` to divide words in path names
I must be sure to find every line where I may accidentally wrote `.\something\like\this.php`.
I'm trying to use Sublime Text Folder Search function with **regexp** but I really suck at those, so please help

**Note:** The title refers to the fact that I also tried to just search for each use of `\`, but it gives me thousands unreadable results for `\\\\, \n, \t, \", \', etc.`.

Comment: I blindly tried this \\(?!"|'|\|n|t)

Comment: You can try using an online regex tester to brush up your regex skills. You can put the data in , and refine your regex until you are happy with it. https://regex101.com/

Comment: So, you just want to check if a string contains a ``\`` that is not escaping a specific char? Try ``^[^\\]*(?:\\[ertaf'"nb\\][^\\]*)*$``. If it does not match, the string contains a ``\`` that is not escaping the chars defined inside `[...]`. See https://regex101.com/r/WXgJcr/2. You may add more known escape chars into the character class.

Answer (score 0):

PARTIALLY SOLVED

I did this /\(?!n|t|\"|\'|/)/g and it kinda solved my problem

I'm not sure this answer correctly my initial question though